# The repository [myname] has been retired and cannot be reused

Tags: git, github, repository

I don't know what I did, but I accidentally deleted a repo on GitHub and it's important that it exists as several projects use it. Luckily I still have the code on my machine but when I push it says the repo must exist, and when I try to recreate the repo I get "The repository [myname] has been retired and cannot be reused". How can I undo/get around this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Try creating a new repository on github with the same name as the old one, and then try to push to it. You might need to remove and re-add the remote locally in order to synchronize remote references though, never done this exact type of recovery so not sure how git behaves.

Comment: Trying to recreate the repo is where I get the error message mentioned above.

Comment: This is strictly a GitHub issue, nothing to do with Git or repositories in general. You'll have to contact the GitHub admins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the organization name
2. Create a repository
3. Change the name of the organization back

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).